# Amazon Redshift UPSERT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to do an upsert with a stage table when copying data from S3.

I want to do this because I want to be able to backfill the data (or launch the process more than just once), and right now it was creating duplicate rows.

I see a bunch of responses that show how to do a `DELETE from {table} USING {stage_table} WHERE {table.primarykey} = {stage_table.primarykey}`

The thing is that I want to do that with a generic function, this means.. how can I access the primary key somehow 'automatically'? Because "primarykey" or "primaryKey" like I read in many places does not work. I am guessing it is just pseudo-code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*EDIT*

The idea is to execute the upsert like this:

[transaction]

```
connection.execute("CREATE TEMP TABLE {stage_table} (like {table});".format(stage_table=stage_table, table=text(self.table)))
connection.execute(self.clean(self.compile_query(copy)))
connection.execute("DELETE FROM {table} USING {stage_table} WHERE {table}.primarykey = {stage_table}.primarykey;".format(stage_table=stage_table, table=text(self.table)))
connection.execute("INSERT INTO {table} SELECT * FROM {stage_table};".format(stage_table=stage_table, table=text(self.table)))
connection.execute("DROP TABLE {stage_table};".format(stage_table=stage_table))
```

[end transaction]

Comment: Nevermind. Fixed it by adding a parameter to my custom operator that is "primary_key" in which you need to pass the primary key of whatever table you want to COPY to. Easy. I guess it can't be done any other way.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question if it will not be of assistance to other people. (There is no way to generically refer to a public key.)